# So how one determine the partial derivative of this function?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f=\sqrt {\left| xy \right|}$ and my lecture note claim that $f_x(0,0)=0$ without giving any step. So how one determine the partial derivative of this function? Moreover is it true that $x\to 0^-$, it seems that $f_x(x,y)=|y|{-1\over2\sqrt {-x}}$ right?

Comment: Apart from being wrong (see my answer), your last sentence does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$, it is trivial that $f_x(x,0)=0$, which explains why the notes don't give any steps.

For the other question, that's not right. In general, if $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ then $f_x(x,y)=g'(x)h(y)$. In the present case, you need to replace $|y|$ by $\sqrt{|y|})$.

Comment: So if $|y|$ is replaced by $\sqrt {|y|}$ then it is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, if you replace the nonsensical $x\to0^-$ by $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the definition and we find this result:
$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{0}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}0=0.$$